# Syntax error on token "start", Identifier expected after this token

Tags: java

This code doesn't work, how do I get rid of the start error

```
Thread enemySpawner = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            for (Slender p : enemies) {
                p.spawnEnemy(g);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    enemySpawner.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Place the statement

```
enemySpawner.start();
```

in a code block such as a method rather than the class block